# How to select column from string in efcore?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am looking for a solution to select a single column based on the column name. The type of columns I want to select is always string. Like so:

```
_dbContext.MyModel.Select("Name")...
```

I wanted to create a extension method:

```
_dbContext.MyModel.SelectFromString("Name")
```

It should allow nested selects, like:

```
_dbContext.MyModel.SelectFromString("Child.Name")
```

Extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<T> SelectFromString<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string column)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, column);
    
    //...

    return query.Select(lambda);
}
```

Not sure how to create the lambda. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually it is easy, but do you understand that `Select` changes result type? Or you want to return the same type, but filled with only ONE property?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking to return string or id and string. The idea is to build a autocomplete/suggestions feature that I can reuse for multiple columns of a model.

Comment: Still is not clear which type do you want to return?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I want to return string.

Comment: Will prepare solution, but correct function signature in question to return `IQueryable<string>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method projects any property to string and returns  `IQueryable<string>`. Nested properties also supported.

```cs
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<string> SelectFromString<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string column)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
        var property = MakePropPath(parameter, column);

        if (property.Type != typeof(string))
        {
            if (property.Type != typeof(object))
                property = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));

            property = Expression.Call(_toStringMethod, property);
        }

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(property, parameter);

        return query.Select(lambda);
    }

    private static Expression MakePropPath(Expression objExpression, string path)
    {
        return path.Split('.').Aggregate(objExpression, Expression.PropertyOrField);
    }

    private static MethodInfo _toStringMethod = typeof(Convert).GetMethods()
        .Single(m =>
            m.Name == nameof(Convert.ToString) && m.GetParameters().Length == 1 &&
            m.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType == typeof(object)
        );
}
```